# Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load pngt

Tags: android, android-studio, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

I am new android application developer.I Integrate ocr for my app but when I run my app I got  Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load pngt,lept,less file.
I import this project from github **https://github.com/priyankvex/Easy-Ocr-Scanner-Android** 
when I scan any file from camera than project unfortunately stop.any idea about this is 
issue like

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load pngt from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscanner-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscanner-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
                                                                                             at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
                                                                                             at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
                                                                                             at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:44)
                                                                                             at com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo.ImageProcessingThread.scanImage(ImageProcessingThread.java:148)
                                                                                             at com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo.ImageProcessingThread.doInBackground(ImageProcessingThread.java:58)
                                                                                             at com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo.ImageProcessingThread.doInBackground(ImageProcessingThread.java:26)
                                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
05-05 17:20:28.826 10978-10978/com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscanner E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4246f6c0 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:425)
                                                                                            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:250)
                                                                                            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
                                                                                            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
                                                                                            at com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo.MainActivity.onOcrScanStarted(MainActivity.java:65)
                                                                                            at com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo.ImageProcessingThread.onPreExecute(ImageProcessingThread.java:51)
                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
                                                                                            at com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo.EasyOcrScanner.onImageTaken(EasyOcrScanner.java:46)
                                                                                            at com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:51)
                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5456)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3549)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3596)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This app like read business card reader.please help......